# Problem with XPS 15 9650 - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS - No Restart, No Shutting Down

Tags: 14.04

I bought a Dell XPS 15 one month ago in order to install Linux on it in dual boot. I installed dual boot Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with Windows 10. But The problem is Ubuntu hangs on shutdown/restart. I faced  the same  problem with Linux Mint, Linux Lite, Lubuntu and Ubuntu-Gnome.

I tried these commands but nothing changed:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get update # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # Installs updates (new ones)
```

Comment: Any reason for using an almost 4 years old Ubuntu release? If not you'd be much better with 16.04.3 LTS or the current, non-LTS, 17.10. In any case the XPS line also comes with Nvidia graphics for which Nvidia proprietary drivers are required for performance.